# Отладка работы CMS (Apache)

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache, cms

В общем у меня такая проблема:
Мне нужно развернуть сервер (**LAMP**) с **CMS**.

1. Я установил все необходимые пакеты.
2. Залил файлы CMS на сервер.
3. В конфиге настроил базу.
4. Перезагрузил сервер.

И теперь когда я захожу в браузере на сервер, то попадаю на стандартную страницу после установки Apache2 (она тоже есть в файлах CMS под: index.html), вместо админ панели;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот теперь вопрос: **Где можно посмотреть что работает не так** (какой-нибудь лог ошибок) в общем с чего начать?

Comment: А удалить этот `она тоже есть в файлах CMS под: index.html` пробовали?

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov получаю HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: а что у вас в `.htaccess` ?

Comment: @Николай Габараев Уже решил. Некоторые функции устарели для 7 версии PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему так (может кому поможет):

В файл index.php вставил:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "l");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Теперь я могу увидеть нужные мне ошибки. *Конкретно в моем случае некоторые функции устарели для новой версии PHP.*

И еще можно посмотреть тут `/var/log/apache2/error.log`